# Match Against unveiled

Tags: mysql

I'd like to understand the behind the scene of MATCH AGAINST.
It returns a score from 0 to 10 but I don't understand the criteria. I was just able to see that trying to match the exact string it returns 0.0906190574169159 while if the string is not contained at all it returns 0. Any enlightment?

Comment: Read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Comment: @ghenghy thank you but I already read it. Unfortunately I could not find an answer to this question, unless you help me to sort it out

Answer (score 0):

So I said read this, but you say it isn't enough:  dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.ht‌​ml

The relevant passage is this:

"When MATCH() is used in a WHERE clause, as in the example shown earlier, the rows returned are automatically sorted with the highest relevance first. Relevance values are nonnegative floating-point numbers. Zero relevance means no similarity. Relevance is computed based on the number of words in the row (document), the number of unique words in the row, the total number of words in the collection, and the number of rows that contain a particular word."

If you take the example tables and insertions on that page and run this query:

```
SELECT MATCH (title,body)
    AGAINST ('database' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) FROM articles;
```

You get:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| MATCH (title,body)
        AGAINST ('database' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                      0.22764469683170319 |
|                                                                        0 |
|                                                                        0 |
|                                                                        0 |
|                                                      0.22764469683170319 |
|                                                                        0 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

For the rows that return a zero, there was no match, for the others, the value is a ranking based on how "good" it thinks the matches are.  In this case, the match is the same, so the values are the same.  If instead, you ran:

```
SELECT MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('Database comparison' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) FROM articles;
```

You get:

```
+--------------------+
| 0.0906190574169159 |
|                  0 |
|                  0 |
|                  0 |
| 0.6961383819580078 |
|                  0 |
+--------------------+
```

Note the values are different now.  The first non-zero result has a lower score as only some of it matches now, while the other has a much higher score indicating a better match.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I wished was an explaination of how accuracy is computed. If I have a single fulltext column and I search for a string that matches entirely a row I would expect that row to match with the maximum accuracy, but it is not the case. So I'd like to understand the occurrency weight in the collection and why it is capped to 10